# In netbeans project category java folder is missing

Tags: java, netbeans

i installed the netbeans IDE and java SEDK today. and the problem is i cant see the java folder in the project category when i tried to create a new project.[image]

---

Comment: Which version and type of Netbeans IDE did you download?

Comment: Try to download from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

Comment: java version "1.8.0_144" .     JDK 8u141 with NetBeans 8.2  .

Comment: Had you set the environmental variables of java?

Comment: i'm new to java. but anyway i'm thankful to your efforts to help me because i founded out that instead of going to new projects if we go to open projects then jva folder can be seen in the categories. but i want to write the code and compile & run it through my mac terminal. can you me help me out how to do it??

Answer (score 8):

It looks like Java SE is not active in your Netbeans installation. To properly use Java SE features you have to follow [these steps](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-embedded.html):

> 1. Choose Tools > Plugins from the main IDE's toolbar.
> 2. In the Plugins dialog box, click the Installed tab and select Java SE in the list of available features.
> 3. Click Activate.
> 4. At the Welcome panel of the Installer dialog box, click Activate. When the activation is successfully completed, click Finish.
> 5. Click Close to close the Plugins dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

1.First go for Tools -> Plugins.

2.Then search for Java SE in available plugins and download Java

3.Go in installed plugins.

4.Activate plugin and that's all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The @acm's answer is right. but you need attention that you are adding a new file at beginning of the Netbeans. 
To resolve this problem, after you activated java SE as @acm's answer, you need to `create a new project` not `new file` on NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

In latest versions of NetBeans(12.6). You can create a console application from the following steps.
New Project > Java With Ant > Java Application
[image]